# Can I make zoom working in ApexCharts heatmap?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts

I'm using Apexcharts in my application to draw some charts and one of them is heatmap. I have a lot of fileds in it so it would be useful if I could zoom it in. ApexCharts already have zoom feature and it is working in other charts. I also have zoom toolbox in my heatmap but it has no effect. Is there any way to make zoom working in ApexCharts heatmaps or is it not implemented yet? I haven't found anything on oficial website. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. Zooming in the ApexCharts heatmap is not implemented.

Comment: And do you think it will be in future or should I look for another way?